# Command R browser refresh in TextMate 2

Tags: textmate, textmate2

Using the HTMLbundle in TextMate version 2.0-alpha.9503, OSX 10.9. I have a html page open in the editor. When I press command R the first time it switches me to Chrome and refreshes the page. On subsequent command R keypress, I get switched to the Chrome window but there is no refresh, and then when I switch back to textMate I get a "Run" dialog and the message:

```
No Makefile found.
Set TM_MAKE_FILE in Preferences → Variable.
```

So obviously after the initial command R, the key combination is triggering a run dialog, but I'm not sure why.

Very new to TextMate so I'm not sure if this is something I am doing wrong, or perhaps I need to be on a more stable version of TextMate.

Any help would be appreciated, this seems like a really cool feature if I could get it to work

Thanks

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Dialog you posted is from the Make bundle...

Make sure your document type is set to HTML before pressing ⌘-R (via the menu on the bottom left or by pressing ⇧⌥^H).

If this does not help, try uninstalling the Make bundle. Normally this behavior shouldn't happen even if the Make bundle is installed, can't reproduce it here. But it's worth a try.

Comment: Thanks kwood. The document was identified as html in the bottom left. Disabling the Make bundle stopped the dialog from appearing. For the most part when I press ⌘-R with the make bundle disabled Chrome becomes active and refreshes. Intermittantly Chrome refuses to actually refresh when it becomes active, not sure why. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Use the proper file type, which we can select from the bottom menu.

For example, for running java program, we have to select java as the file type

[image]